# Entity Framework Core Navigation Properties column is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table `TodoWorkspace` in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TodoWorkspace]
(
    [IdTodoWorkspace] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Private] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [IdUser] INT NOT NULL,
    [Position] INT  NULL,
    [InsertDate] DATETIME NULL,
    [UserLM] INT NULL,
    [DateLM] DATETIME NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdTodoWorkspace] ASC)
        WITH(FILLFACTOR = 90),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TodoWorkspace_ToAdminUser]
        FOREIGN KEY ([IdUser])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[UtentiAdmin] ([IdUtente])
);
```

The class generated automatically with Scaffold command is the following:

```
public partial class TodoWorkspace
{
    public int IdTodoWorkspace { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool Private { get; set; }
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InsertDate { get; set; }
    public int? UserLM { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateLM { get; set; }
    public int? Position { get; set; }

    public virtual UtentiAdmin IdUserNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<TodoList> TodoList { get; set; } = new List<TodoList>();
    public virtual ICollection<TodoWorkspaceUsers> TodoWorkspaceUsers { get; set; } = new List<TodoWorkspaceUsers>();
}
```

I have a method that select all the rows from the table with linq:

```
public static List<TodoWorkspace> GetEntities(int parIdLoggedUser, Entities parCtx = null)
{
    Entities context = parCtx ?? new Entities();

    List<TodoWorkspace> toRet = new List<TodoWorkspace>();

    try
    {
        var ent = (from c in context.TodoWorkspace
                   orderby c.Position
                   select c);
        toRet.AddRange(ent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        toRet = null;
        LOG.WriteExceptionLog(ex, parIdLoggedUser);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (parCtx == null)
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }

    return toRet;
}
```

The exception I get is

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: the name of column 'IdUserNavigationIdUtente' is not valid.

Scaffold command

```
Scaffold-DbContext  -Connection name=Entities 
        -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
        -OutputDir Models -force -Context almareaEntities 
        -NoPluralize -Namespace almareaEFCore -UseDatabaseNames
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell EF that the foreign key is IdUser, eg

```
[ForeignKey("IdUser")]
public virtual UtentiAdmin UtentiAdmin { get; set; } = null!;
```

Comment: This class is automatically generated, Do I have to add some word to Scaffold command? I put Scaffold Command in my question

Comment: Generated by what?  The built-in scaffolding would have configured the entity correctly.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli  Did you leave out the OnModelCreating that was generated?

Comment: generated by scaffold command Scaffold-DbContext  -Connection name=Entities -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force -Context almareaEntities -NoPluralize -Namespace almareaEFCore -UseDatabaseNames

Comment: It should have created another code file with the fluent configuration.  You can force it to annotate your classes instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#use-mapping-attributes-aka-data-annotations

Comment: adding -DataAnnotations to Scaffold command works, the automatically generated classes have Annotations like [ForeignKey("IdUser")] and the exception doesn't throw anymore.